# Realm get ID of saved record

Tags: swift, realm

I need to get the id of the record that was just saved to pass the information on a segue.

How can I return of get the id of the record saved?

Model:

```
class Month: Object {

    @objc dynamic public private(set) var id = ""
    @objc dynamic public private(set) var month = Date()
    @objc dynamic public private(set) var beg:Int = 0

override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
}
```

the write:

```
static func addMonthToRealm(month: Date, beg: Int) {

do {
     let realm = try Realm( )
     try realm.write {
     realm.add(month)
        try realm.commitWrite()
      }
    } catch {
       debugPrint("Error adding run to realm!")
    }
}
```

Using swift 4.2 and Realm 3.1

thank you.

Comment: how and when is the `id` generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. First of all, you're trying to save a `Date` object to `Realm` instead of saving your custom `Month` object. Secondly, never call `commitWrite` inside a `write` transaction. You only need to call `commitWrite` if you are using `beginWrite` to start a `write` transaction rather than using `realm.write` with a closure.

```
static func addMonthToRealm(date: Date, beg: Int) -> String? {
    let month = Month()
    month.month = date
    month.beg = beg    
    do {
        let realm = try Realm( )
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(month)
        }
        return month.id
    } catch {
       debugPrint("Error adding run to realm!")
       return nil
    }
}
```

You also need to modify your `Month` object definition to generate a unique `id`.

```
class Month: Object {

    @objc dynamic public private(set) var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic public private(set) var month = Date()
    @objc dynamic public private(set) var beg:Int = 0

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comments.  My "month" was not a date it was the name of the object. Bad naming on my part - sorry.  I have actually have remained it. I also have the unique ID set in the init().  self.id = UUID().uuidString.lowercased().   I hope this is ok.I think I got that approach from the Realm site?  Still not figured out how to get ID after save.  I am just grabbing the last add file? Cheers.

Comment: @diogenes from your code in the question it was actually a `Date`. I've updated my answer so that the `addMonthToRealm` function returns the `id` of the added `Month` object or `nil` in case it couldn't be added. You can simply use this return value.